# How to hide overflowed element but only on the top?

Tags: html, css

I only want to hide elements thats overflowing on the top. In my document blue is the background img and the child is skewed div.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5frrfawx/)

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class=child>

    </div>
</div>

.parent {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
      transform: skewY(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(20deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(20deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to add another parent with `overflow: hidden`:

```css
.ovh-parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(20deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="ovh-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class=child>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does this work out for you? See the preview below...

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: 1+ Nice answer! And it's simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add another div outside of the parent that would help with hiding the overflow.

```css
.overflow{
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(20deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class=child>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add another ancestor if you use this trick:

- Add `overflow: hidden` to hide overflow
- Increase the height to avoid clipping the overflow at the bottom
- Add a negative margin to prevent the previous step from affecting following contents
- Use a background image instead of a background color. For example, use a gradient.
- Use `background-size` to set the size of that background image. Do not repeat the background.

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, red) no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 200px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(20deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
Lorem ipsum
```